# What process should I use to build a linux config page?

Tags: php, linux, twitter-bootstrap, configuration

I have a Linux server with some config files that need to be updated by the user, I would like the ability to add entries to these files from a web UI instead of a user editing the files directly.

I will be using bootstrap for the UI.

But I would like to know what would be the approach or best technology to use to keep these files up-to-date or manage their contents.

I have a good understanding of PHP and always used databases for storing information - but I'm lost about how to tackle this.

File one is called jobs.yml looks like this

```
#Convert Audio
job1:
 label: Convert to Text to MP3
 watch: /home/media/convert_audio/to_mp3
 events: ['write_close', 'move_to']
 recursive: false
 command: /home/media/bin/to_mp3 "$filename"

job12:
 label: Convert to Text to WAV
 watch: /home/media/convert_audio/to_wav
 events: ['write_close', 'move_to']
 recursive: false
 command: /home/media/bin/to_wav "$filename"
```

File two is actually a collection of bash files or scripts (I guess this could be templated)

```
#!/bin/bash
o="$1"
o="${o##*/}"
o="${o%.*}"
ffmpeg -i $1 -qscale 0 "/home/media/convert_videos/converted/$o.mpg"
mv "$1" /home/media/convert_videos/processed/
```

I would ultimately like to Add/Remove and edit entries

Comment: What format is used for your config files ? .ini or other ? can you explain more precisely what you mean by "keep these files up-to-date" ?

Comment: updated to add samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For yml files, there are PHP functions that permit to easily manage them : [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.yaml.php). 
You can also found libraries which add more features.

For bash files, they are like other files and you can read/write content with PHP file functions ([PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filesystem.php)). But you will have to write your own logic to append/remove new lines.

It maybe a good idea to use a database to store all lines which have to be in each files. You will can rebuild all file content from DB (it will be simpler to add/remove lines).

To finish, take care of what your **users write in your bash files**, it's a **potential security breach**.

Comment: Thank you this is great - It's given me a good place to start!